# TextView does not show log

Tags: java, android

Okay I am new with android and i have been following a course but there are somethings that i don't understand.

This is `LifeCycleT` activity.

```
package com.example.killtheviolence.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LifeCycleT extends Activity {
    StringBuilder builde = new StringBuilder();
    TextView textview;

    private void  log(String text) {
        Log.d("LifeCycleT", text);
        builde.append( builde.toString() );
        builde.append("\n");
        textview.setText(builde.toString());
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText(builde.toString());
        setContentView(textview);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        log("resume");
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        log("paused");
        if(isFinishing()) {
            log("death");
        }
    }
}
```

Where this came from? From a `ListView`.

```
package com.example.killtheviolence.myapplication;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    String prueva[] = {"LifeCycleT","item2","item3","item4",
            "item5 ", "item6 "};

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSate){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceSate);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, prueva));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String gate = prueva[position];

        try {
            Class<?> inst;
            inst = Class.forName("com.example.killtheviolence.myapplication." + gate);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, inst);
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

That's the main activity.

What I want to do show in the `TextView` the `Log.d` in the screen but I get an error:

> Unable to resume activity
>   {com.example.killtheviolence.myapplication/com.example.killtheviolence.myapplication.LifeCycleT}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

So I looked for a reason (meaning for a `NullPointerException` and it was that 
I used `TextView` before initializing on the line `textview.setText(builde.toString());`
What I did was create an instance of `TextView` in `log` function.

```
private void  log(String text) {
    Log.d("LifeCycleT", text);
    builde.append(builde.toString());
    builde.append("\n");
    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText(builde.toString());
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText(builde.toString());
    setContentView(textview);
}
```

Why have I to create two instances of `TextView`? And why have I to `setText` twice? Why doesn't it show anything in the `TextView`? (only shows when i wrote a `"string"` in the arguments of `setText`.)

Comment: The problem is not Android, but the way you're using `StringBuilder`. I guess you should go over the basics once again before you start developing an Android app.

Comment: Why are you making a TextView class by hand instead of inflating a layout?

Comment: because this is my first android app and i dont known about what you are talking about i just known java... and i am following a curse ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix your `onCreate` to set the field parameter not a local parameter:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textview = new TextView(this); // << This used to be a local var, thats why NPE
    textview.setText(builde.toString());
    setContentView(textview);
}
```

Then remove the 2nd creation of the `TextView` from `log`

```
private void log(String text) {
    Log.d("LifeCycleT", text);
    builde.append("\n");
    builde.append(text);
    textview.setText(builde.toString());
}
```

Also notice that I changed your `StringBuilder` to append the text that you pass as a parameter into your `log` method